Specific bytes appear in memory after the program runs, how to find out what codes cause them?
My C language program uses AES encryption, which can be easily found by scanning program memory to see if sbox bytes exist or not. (Simply searching 63 7C 77 7B F2 6B 6F C5 exists or not)
I don't want hackers to know my encryption algorithm so easily, so I want to encrypt sbox.
Anyway, I already set 0x00 to all sbox bytes in source code, it can't be detected in binary executable, but after program runs, sbox bytes are detected in program memory again.
I think codes somewhere else generate sbox dynamically, but I just couldn't find out where it is.
So is there any easy way to find out which line or which source code file generates specific bytes?
If the answer is no, I am thinking about Visual Studio debugging.
After executed one line of source code, pause the program, scan the whole program memory, and see if there are specific bytes in there. Repeat this over and over until find it.
But I am not familiar with Visual Studio, so I am not sure if this even possible.

If an adversary can run your program under a debugger, there is no way you can protect it. OTOH, it doesn't really help them to know that your app is using AES (an industry standard encryption algorithm) unless they also have access to the keys used, and those should of course not be part of the executable in any form.

I know there isn't a 100% safe way, but I wanted to make things as difficult as possible.
Not only the AES key, but I don't even want adversaries to know the encryption algorithm either.

But you need the sbox to be in memory at some point, right? Is your goal to clear it after use or do you plan to reimplement the whole algorithm to never write the sbox to memory?

Yes, encrypted sbox need to be decrypted before being used, but I don't want decrypted bytes to appear in memory at any time. So yes, I need to modify codes to make this bytes pattern never show up in memory. But that's later. Right now, I need to figure out what codes generate sbox bytes in runtime.

Visual studio allows you to add a "data breakpoint" with the Debug/New breakpoint/Data breakpoint..." menu command. Basically you can set a breakpoint that triggers once the contents of a given memory address change. It sounds like you know which address contains the data that is changing, so this should allow you to find what code is changing it.
For more info, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2022#BKMK_set_a_data_breakpoint_native_cplusplus

No, it doesn't appear like OP knows the location since they talk about scanning all of the programs memory to see if the byte-pattern popped up anywhere. If this is some intermediate value written by a library then it might even be in a dynamically allocated region. Cool debugger feature though, so thanks for that.

I can't seem to find a fixed address. Here's what I do: run my program, create a dump file for the process in task manager, wait 10 seconds, create another dump file, and repeat this until it gets 5 dump files. And search sbox bytes in every dump file. Unfortunately, sbox bytes were found at different addresses among the 5 dump files. I don't know if this is the correct operation though.

You could automate the search to find out what areas of memory are readable and scan through them. See  https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8297/proc-self-maps-equivalent-on-windows/8299#8299. You could do that either having the scanning code within the program itself, or outside of it. That could allow you to narrow down the time when the bytes appear - you could reach a time resolution of 10 ms rather than 10s - though it might still be hard to find the exact location of code that writes those bytes.

This: https://sourceforge.net/p/lukestackwalker/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/sampler.cpp is something that I wrote that runs another program, pauses it periodically and samples the callstack and reads process memory (but not the whole memory map).  If the target program is not somethign you wrote and you would want to do the scanning from an external program, it might be a suitable starting point (or not).
